# Change or edit locale settings of browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I would like to easily change the locale setting on my browser (Chrome or Firefox).

When I surf to certain sites they automatically localize, I would like to be able to change that as some sites don't offer a way to change it or override any changes I make in the locale settings of the URL.

I know there are different ways for websites to detect what my language/location should be, but the most used is via IP tracing.

The most ideal would be a extension or add-on with whom I can simply change the settings to a desired language/country. Does such an extension or add-on exist?

I've tried looking for ways to achieve this but can't find any (maybe I'm not using the right keywords when searching).

Comment: Most of these sites localize according to your IP address and what country it is in, so the browser can't influence it

Comment: Sites that localize according to IP are not following best practices. The problem with doing that is that many people access websites from locations which are not their home country. Just wanted to mention that even though it really isn't the question you've asked.

Comment: Actually that is what is going on, I'm of Greek descent, living in the Netherlands and for my work I travel I sometimes travel to France, Spain or the UK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extension called Quick language switcher,it will help you try that one.To download go to https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-language-switcher/pmjbhfmaphnpbehdanbjphdcniaelfie

Comment: I tried this extension but it didn't work, I just activated it again to see if I was doing something wrong and got it to work (maybe it needed a reboot or something). Thanks!